# Implementing Logistic Regression in MATLAB

Tags: regression, matlab

I have a data set of 13 attributes where some are categorical and some are continuous (can be converted to categorical). I need to use logistic regression to create a model that predicts the responses of a row and find the prediction's accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity.

- Can/Should I use cross validation to divide my data set and get the results?
- Is there any code sample on how to go about doing this? (I'm new to all of this)
- Should I be using mnrfit/mnrval or glmfit/glmval? What's the difference and how do I choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to determine how well the model can predict *unseen* data you can use cross validation.
In Matlab, you can use `glmfit` to fit the logistic regression model and `glmval` to test it.

Here is a sample of Matlab code that illustrates how to do it, where `X` is the feature matrix and `Labels` is the class label for each case, `num_shuffles` is the number of repetitions of the cross-validation while `num_folds` is the number of folds:

```
for j = 1:num_shuffles
    indices = crossvalind('Kfold',Labels,num_folds);
    for i = 1:num_folds
        test = (indices == i); train = ~test;
        [b,dev,stats] = glmfit(X(train,:),Labels(train),'binomial','logit'); % Logistic regression
        Fit(j,i) = glmval(b,X(test,:),'logit')';
    end
end
```

`Fit` is then the fitted logistic regression estimate for each test fold. Thresholding this will yield an estimate of the predicted class for each test case. Performance measures are then calculated by comparing the predicted class label against the actual class label. Averaging the performance measures across all folds and repetitions gives an estimate of the model performance on unseen data.

Comment: Could you please edit the answer to include the difference between "mnrfit/mnrval" and "glmfit/glmval". I mean which to use where ?

Comment: As far as I known mnrfit/mnrval refer to multinomial logistic regression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) i.e. generalised logistic regression the case where there are more than 2 classes. So for more than 2 classes use mnrfit/mnrval, for binary classification use above.